# Foreign keys output PHP

Tags: php, foreign-keys

I'm tring to get a hold of foreign keys, as I need to use it for a gallery, where each uploaded image is assigned to a photographer, these photographers also need to be showed in the menu.

I have followed [this guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/mysql-foreign-keys-quicker-database-development/) and everything went well. I now need to output the data with PHP - this I can't figure out.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM borrowed WHERE employee.id = 'Reck' JOIN employee ON employee.id = borrowed.employeeid";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>

<? echo $row['lastname']; ?>

<?php

   }

?>
```

I get the error **Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/galleri/test.php on line 12**

Line 12 is the while loop.

Comment: JOIN comes before WHERE clauses, as a result `mysqli_query` fails `(false)`, then domino effects `mysqli_fetch_array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error within your query please refer query structure [How to use joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339251/how-to-write-a-mysql-join-query)

Within your query `join` is after `where` condition but it must be before `where`. It should be like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM borrowed JOIN employee ON employee.id = borrowed.employeeid WHERE employee.id = 'Reck'";
```

and your code

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM borrowed JOIN employee ON employee.id = borrowed.employeeid WHERE employee.id = 'Reck'";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['lastname'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have now removed the error. But it doesn't output anything, just a blank page.

I have used "<? echo $row['lastname']; ?>" is that not right?

Comment: I have updated my answer you had an error within your code `<? echo $row['lastname']; ?>` instead you have to write as `<?php  echo $row['lastname']; ?>`

Comment: @NicolajReck `var_dump($result);` before the while and tell me what it returns